# better reuse of json file in backbone app using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, backbone.js

At the moment I have a basic app that reads of a json file.

the way I have constructed this so far is

i have a router that calls different functions

```
routes: {

        'products/productList' : 'showProducts',
        'products/list/:productID' : 'showProductsList',
        'products/view/:productID/:productTypeID' : 'showProductsView'

}

showProducts:function(){

 var productList=new Products();
 var productListView=new ProductListView({collection:productList});
 productListView.bind('renderCompleted:Products',this.changePage,this);

 productListView.update();

}

showProductsList:function(productID){

 var productTypeList=new ProductTypeCollection();
 var productTypeListView=new ProductTypeListView({collection:productTypeList});
 productTypeListView.bind('renderCompleted:ProductsType',this.changePage,this);
 productTypeListView.update(productID);
}
```

so I created a model for product

```
var Product=Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults:{
        id:"",
        name:'',
        longName:'',
        productID:''
    }
});

return Product;
```

and a collection for it

```
var Products=Backbone.Collection.extend({
 model:Product,

 fetch:function(){
        var self=this;
        var tmpItem;

    var jqxhr = $.getJSON("data/product.json")
          .success(function(data, status, xhr) { 

    $.each(data.data.productTypeList, function(i,item){
              tmpItem=new Product({id:item.id,name:item.name,longName:item.longName, productID:i});
              self.add(tmpItem);

            });
            //dispatch customized event
            self.trigger("fetchCompleted:Products");
          })
          .error(function() { alert("error"); })
          .complete(function() {
                console.log("fetch complete + " + this);
          });             
      }
});

return Products;
```

and then a model for product type

```
var ProductType=Backbone.Model.extend({
//default attributes 
    defaults:{
        id:"",
        name:'',
        productID:'',
        productTypeID:''
    }
});

return ProductType;
```

with its own collection

```
var ProductsType=Backbone.Collection.extend({
 model:ProductType,

 fetch:function(){
        var self=this;
        var tmpItem;

    var jqxhr = $.getJSON("data/product.json")
          .success(function(data, status, xhr) { 

    $.each(data.data.productTypeList, function(i,item){
              tmpItem=new Product({id:item.id,name:item.name,longName:item.longName, productID:i});
              self.add(tmpItem);

            });
            //dispatch customized event
            self.trigger("fetchCompleted:ProductsType");
          })
          .error(function() { alert("error"); })
          .complete(function() {
                console.log("fetch complete + " + this);
          });             
      }
});

return ProductsType;
```

these each then have thier own views

```
  var ProductListView = Backbone.View.extend({

template: _.template(productViewTemplate),

update:function(){
  //set callback of the event "fetchCompleted:Products" 
  this.collection.bind('fetchCompleted:Products',this.render,this);
  this.collection.fetch();
},

render: function(){
  this.$el.empty();
  //compile template using the data fetched by collection
  this.$el.append(this.template({data:this.collection.toJSON()}));
  this.trigger("renderCompleted:Products",this);
  return this;
}
});

return ProductListView;
```

and the productType view

var ProductListTypeView = Backbone.View.extend({

```
template: _.template(productViewTypeTemplate),

update:function(productID){
  //set callback of the event "fetchCompleted:Products" 
  this.collection.bind('fetchCompleted:ProductsType',this.render,this);
  this.collection.fetch(productID);
},

render: function(){
  this.$el.empty();
  //compile template using the data fetched by collection
  this.$el.append(this.template({data:this.collection.toJSON()}));
  this.trigger("renderCompleted:ProductsType",this);

  return this;
}
});

return ProductListTypeView;
```

obviously its crazy to load the same json file multiple times as this will slow the app down but I am wondering how do I get the correct place in the JSON file

you can see that the first collection gets data.productTypeList and the second one gets data.productTypeList[productID] as this is passed in from the url.

Also there are triggers set when the json has loaded which enable the views.

I know the structure of this is bad but would welcome some suggestions

I am guessing i need to make a model that has all the lower level data in and add them with one collection.

Is this best to use thge technique I am where I am creating a model and then using a getJSON command where I say exactly what to add in the new Product call or I am better off using a url within my collection that just points to a json file?

Here is an example of the json file

http://demo.stg.brightonconsulting.net.au/templates/tests/backboneJQMProducts/data/product.json

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Curious to why you overwrote the fetch method in your collections? If the data from the file needs to be manipulated accordingly, just use Backbone's [parse](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) method. Depending on the size of your json file, I would fetch the json file once and store it in an object on application load. From there I would reference the object and pass in the relevant data into my Collection. That way, you don't have to call fetch on each view. Just render the view because your data would have already been loaded.